# How to pass open_range_list to function for use in 'inside' operator

Tags: system-verilog

I have a function that returns 1 or 0 if a queue contains an element. I want to enhance this function to check if the queue contains any element in a set by using the 'inside' operator. For example, my function works like this:

```
function bit queue_exists(int n);
    foreach(m_queue[x]) begin
        if (m_queue[x] == n) return 1;
    end
    return 0;
endfunction
```

Now I want my function to work like this:

```
function bit queue_exists(/*open_range_list elements*/);
    foreach(m_queue[x]) begin
        if (m_queue[x] inside {elements}) return 1;
    end
    return 0;
endfunction
```

Is it possible to do this in SystemVerilog? I'm not sure what the syntax should be. I'm referencing "open_range_list" from the SV-LRM 1800-2017 Section 11.4.13:

> inside_expression ::= expression inside { open_range_list } // from A.8.3

Answer (score 1):

Declare the function something like this:

```
function bit queue_exists (int elements []);
```

Here is a runnable example:

```
module tb;

int m_queue [$];

function bit queue_exists (int elements []);
    foreach(m_queue[x]) begin
        if (m_queue[x] inside {elements}) return 1;
    end
    return 0;
endfunction

initial begin
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) m_queue.push_back(i);
    $display(queue_exists('{3, 6}));
    $display(queue_exists('{8, 9, 10}));
end

endmodule
```

Output is:

```
1
0
```